# How to split/cut multipolygon region by multiple line segments?

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

I have a polygon region poly1 and another polygon region poly2 ( both are polygon in shapely), then I am taking their symmetric difference which is a multipolygon.

There are line segments which join the vertices of poly1 and poly2. I want to split the multipolygon obtained by the symmetric difference by line segements(these line segments lie on the multipolygon itself).

The code I am running gives error:

```
File "/home/runner/Python/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/ops.py", line 511, in split
    [i for part in geom.geoms for i in SplitOp.split(part, splitter).geoms]
  File "/home/runner/Python/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/ops.py", line 511, in <listcomp>
    [i for part in geom.geoms for i in SplitOp.split(part, splitter).geoms]
  File "/home/runner/Python/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/ops.py", line 535, in split
    raise GeometryTypeError(
shapely.errors.GeometryTypeError: Splitting a Polygon with a MultiLineString is not supported
```

Code-

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon, MultiLineString, LineString
from shapely.ops import split

multipolygon = MultiPolygon([
      Polygon([(7, 10), (8, 11), (9, 11), (8, 10), (7, 9.5), (7, 10)]),
      Polygon([(9.5, 8.5), (10, 9), (10, 10), (11, 9), (9.5, 8.5)])
])
multiline = MultiLineString([
    LineString([(7, 10), (8, 10)]),
    LineString([(8, 10), (8, 11)]),
    LineString([(10, 9), (11, 9 )]),
    LineString([(8, 9), (10, 9)])
])

# Divide multipolygon by lines
divided_multipolygon = split(multipolygon, multiline)

print("Divided MultiPolygon:", divided_multipolygon)
```

How can I achieve my task? Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the individual lines in the MultiLine and split the MultiPolygon in multiple passes...

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon, MultiLineString, LineString
from shapely.ops import split

multipolygon = MultiPolygon(
    [
        Polygon([(7, 10), (8, 11), (9, 11), (8, 10), (7, 9.5), (7, 10)]),
        Polygon([(9.5, 8.5), (10, 9), (10, 10), (11, 9), (9.5, 8.5)]),
    ]
)
multiline = MultiLineString(
    [
        LineString([(7, 10), (8, 10)]),
        LineString([(8, 10), (8, 11)]),
        LineString([(10, 9), (11, 9)]),
        LineString([(8, 9), (10, 9)]),
    ]
)

# Divide multipolygon by lines
for line in multiline.geoms:
    multipolygon = MultiPolygon(split(multipolygon, line).geoms)

print("Divided MultiPolygon:", multipolygon)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was searching for. Really appreciate the help

Comment: in the for each mutli polygon, how do I find the largest line that lies entirely within each polygon? Can you give some suggestions please?

Comment: largest line could be the one with largest [shapely.length](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.length.html#shapely.length), you can check it being entirely within with [shapely.within](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.within.html)

Comment: I guess you are talking about finding the longest segment that is cutting the polygon. I meant, longest line segment starting from anywhere in/on the polygon and ending in/on the polygon.
Please refer/answer this question! -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78123946/longest-line-lying-completely-inside-a-polygon-in-shapely

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because the `split()` operation does not support splitting a `Polygon` with a `MultiLineString`. It expects a single `LineString` to split the `Polygon`.

Your best bet would be to iterate over each `LineString` and updating the `MultiPolygon` for the next iteration using the previous result.

```py
split_polygons = []

for line in multiline:
   result = split(multipolygon, line)
   split_polygons.extend(result)
```

Comment: It is giving error - TypeError: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable.

Comment: I tried something similar but it did not give desired result. Code-

def divide_multipolygon_by_lines(multipolygon, multiline):
    divided_polygons = []
    
     
     for line in multiline.geoms:
         for polygon in multipolygon.geoms:
             split_polygons = split(polygon, line)
             divided_polygons.extend(split_polygons)

     return MultiPolygon(divided_polygons)

It is not giving desired result!